# Firefox Developer Edition 40.0a2 search bar and back arrow not displaying correctly

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-edition

Version 40.0a2 of Firefox Developer Edition is not displaying search bar correctly, including the back arrow. This occured with the update prior to version 40.0a2. Mozilla Developer Network https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Connect seems to suggest this is the place for help.

Link to example image: [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/as551r7xlu6b1up/back%20arrow.png?dl=0)

OS: 64 bit Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: This is actually a silly place to have this question and it is dragging my reputation down! Can it be deleted by the mods?

Answer (score 1):

is your search broken as well? I can't comment your post not enough rep lol.. my search broke on linux but everything else is fine, it crashes when I try to search in the url bar and the search bar just doesn't work

Comment: The search does work for me. In fact everything appears to work fine, its just not displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A recent update of Firefox Developer Edition solved this issue. I am on version 40.0a2 (2015-05-26), and the appearance of the search bar is back to normal.